# writetable commas instead of dots, for the decimal separator

Tags: matlab

I have data stored on a ".mat" file as Matlab numbers, and I want to pretty print this table as a tsv file, I want to replace the decimal dot to a decimal comma, however.

This is what I've tried.

```matlab
measurements=load('Emeasured.mat');
writetable(struct2table(measurements),"messwertelab1.tsv",'Delimiter','\t')
```

Works but the numbers are "ugly", I would use a tool like `num2eng` but I need to localize it so that decimal separator is a comma.

```matlab
nf=java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(java.util.Locale.GERMAN);
nformat=@(num)(nf.format(num))
arrayfun(nformat,measurements.column)
```

seems to error, error message is.

> Unable to assign into Uniform output array 2 at index 1. Set 'UniformOutput' to false.
>
> Caused by:
> Index exceeds Java array dimensions

Why can't I loop over the array?
`nformat(2.124)` gives the expected value.

Comment: Did you try with “Set 'UniformOutput' to false”, as the helpful error message suggests? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html#d123e48258

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think this is an answer, you should post it as one.

Comment: Sorry. I just followed up on the text of the error message that MATLAB gave you, and pointed you to the docs that you can find by typing `doc arrayfun` in MATLAB. I don’t think this should ever have been a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to make `writetable` write output to a table with numbers using commas for decimal separator instead of dots.

```matlab
df=java.text.DecimalFormat("0", ...
    java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(java.util.Locale.GERMAN));
%or the locale you desire.
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);
%340 is the maximum Value.
%When calling the function arrayfun with `UniformOutput` to false
%you get a collection of cells back, this is how to flatten them to a list of strings
vflatten = @(x, varargin) vertcat(x{:});
%This is the callback for arrayfun
nformat=@(num)(string(df.format(num)));
%Finally your formatted arrays.
vflatten(arrayfun(nformat,yourArrayWithNumbers,"UniformOutput",false));
```